# How to show arraylist of Strings in p:dataGrid?

Tags: css, jsf, datagrid, primefaces, panel

I have ajax functionality to add names and show on the same page in a table manner with one image(on left of text) and one "X" image(on right to delete). It should be added like, from left to right and after completing one row, it should start from next row.

So I need to show an arraylist of string in p:datagrid or any other tag which can be used with same functionality.

I tried with combination of ui:repeat and p:panelgrid but I was unable to get datagrid funtionallty. I did not used p:dataTable because it would add new element on bottom side not as I need.

P.S.

```
<h:form>

        <h:selectOneMenu id="recepients" value="#{controller.selected}">
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select" itemValue=""></f:selectItem>
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Info1" itemValue="Info1"></f:selectItem>
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Info2" itemValue="Info2"></f:selectItem>
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Info3" itemValue="Info3"></f:selectItem>
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Info4" itemValue="Info4"></f:selectItem>
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Info5" itemValue="Info5"></f:selectItem>


        </h:selectOneMenu>
        <p:commandButton value="Add" action="#{controller.submit}"
            update="nameslist" />

        <p:dataGrid id="nameslist" value="#{controller.tempNameList}"
            var="name" columns="3">
            <p:column>
                <p:outputLabel value="%" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column>
                <p:outputLabel value="#{name}" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column>
                <p:commandLink value="X" action="#{controller.delete(name)}"
                    update="nameslist">
                </p:commandLink>                


            </p:column>

        </p:dataGrid>
    </h:form>
```

The result should be like this...

% Abc X
% Xyz X
% dfd X

plz consider % as image and X as close symbol

Comment: You forgot to elaborate about the error/problem you're facing. How exactly are you unable to get it to work?

Comment: share some of your code please. it does not hurt :)

Comment: @BalusC After clicking that add button name is added and it should be displayed on screen as tabular form. DataGrid of primefaces provide this solution. But in my case its not accepting arraylist of string

Comment: Please elaborate what exactly you mean with "its not accepting". What exactly happens? It doesn't show the items? Or it threw an exception? Or it shows the items in a wrong way? In any way, it works fine for me (and also on PrimeFaces showcase site). Show some code so that we can point out your mistake. Perhaps you used the wrong attribute or the array list is simply empty.

Comment: @BalusC I have updated now my ques with my code. Plz check.. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<p:dataGrid>` doesn't support `<p:column>`. This column layout is only applicable to `<p:dataTable>`.

Replace all those `<p:column>` by a single grouping component, e.g. `<h:panelGroup>` or maybe `<p:panel>`, exactly as shown on [showcase site](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datagrid.jsf).

```
<p:dataGrid id="nameslist" value="#{controller.tempNameList}" var="name" columns="3">
    <h:panelGroup>
        <p:outputLabel value="%" />
        <p:outputLabel value="#{name}" />
        <p:commandLink value="X" action="#{controller.delete(name)}" update="nameslist" />
    </h:panelGroup>
</p:dataGrid>
```

Comment: Thanks for your ans. When I checked its working for me. I just made changes to commandlink action. If I am giving any parameter then it cause problem. But I need that parameter so that I can pass value to delete. I am getting this exception- /DynamicCss.xhtml at line 43 and column 72 action="#{controller.delete(name)}" Failed to parse the expression [#{controller.delete(name)}]

Comment: You will get this exception when your environment doesn't support EL 2.2.

Comment: So what should I do. I dont have any idea about this.

Comment: Just ask a question here if you can't find answers by search or logically thinking? (e.g.: make sure that your environment supports EL 2.2).

Comment: After adding el-api-2.2.jar and el-impl-2.2 jar to tomcat server and adding <context-param>
    <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.EXPRESSION_FACTORY</param-name>
    <param-value>com.sun.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl</param-value>
</context-param> to web.xml, its working for me. Thanks a lot